# What is the meaning of temperature characteristics in capacitor datasheet?

Tags: capacitor, ceramic

I found a datasheet for a medium voltage ceramic capacitor in door knob form factor.  I'm not familiar with one of the stated characteristics.  Specifically,  the temperature characteristics: +22/-33%. Can someone explain what that means?

[image]

Comment: Bit strange to state it like that. Is any more information given in the datasheet? I would interpret it as up to +22 % increase down to -33 % decrease over the specified temperature range.

Comment: That's most of the datasheet, the rest is for dimensions. I was thinking it how much the characteristics can change in specified temperature range, but I dind't see other manufacturers call it that.

Comment: Ask the manufacturer? In general, brief and “fluffy” datasheet = no sale.

Comment: It may be interpreted as + 22 % capacity -30 °C and -33 % at +  85 °C. But the minimum and maximum capacity may anywhere within the temperature range -30 to +85 °C. I would prefer a precise specification.

Comment: For a much better specification see https://catalogs.kyocera-avx.com/SurfaceMount.pdf on page 30 +

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It refers to the capacitance variation over temperature for Class 2 ceramic capacitors for a Y5T dielectric. Here's a table from Wikipedia on [Ceramic Capacitors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceramic_capacitor):

[image: See this table from Wikipedia]

The +22/-33% rating tells you that the capacitor nominal value can change at the most +22% to -33% over the temperature range, that is the best you can infer from it.

You're better served by looking at the specific component characteristic curve over temperature, but in a nutshell, for a 10uF capacitor, you could expect it to be anywhere from 12.2uF (+22%) to 7.8uF (-33%) — and that is just the change over temperature drifts, DC bias will also have a significant impact.

[Murata](https://ds.murata.co.jp/simsurfing/mlcc.html?lcid=en-us&jis=false&md5=7cf8d0e3ab24bcc658bc91b1e576adbe), for example, has a tool that allows you to see variations  over temperature, DC bias, AC voltage, etc. Here is the capacitance swing for 4.7uF X7T capacitor over its temperature range:

[image]

As you can see, over the temperature range, the capacitance peaks somewhere in middle and then decreases.